# AWS SES Templated Email Variables Are Breaking Cyrillic Letters

Tags: character-encoding, amazon-ses

I am attempting to send templated emails via SES with Cyrillic characters and the encoding is somehow broken when passing the string as a variable. The encoding is absolutely fine up until this point it is passed to the email. Because it's templated instead of a raw email, I think I can avoid encoding to base64 which is what the documentation suggests for raw email.

CHARSET = "UTF-8" is passed as an argument when initializing the email templates. Moving it down into the template itself did not make a difference. If I just put the raw string into the HTML/Text parts of the email, it renders perfectly.

ETA: It appears that SES is encoding the UTF-8 string 'Марійка' into ISO-8859-1 which is 'ÐœÐ°Ñ€Ñ–Ð¹ÐºÐ°'. I might be mistaken but you can see the conversion [here](https://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx)

The string:
`Марійка`

The string as rendered in Gmail:
`ÐœÐ°Ñ€Ñ–Ð¹ÐºÐ°`

The string's encoding as found in 'Show Original' in Gmail:

```
=C3=90=C2=B9=C3=90=C2=BA=C3=90=C2=B0
```

The code to trigger the email:

```
def sendEmail(self, emailType, emailTo, replacements):
        settings = app.emailconfig.EmailConfig(emailType)
        replacements = json.dumps(replacements, ensure_ascii=False, encoding="utf-8")
        try:
            params = {
                "Source": self.EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS,
                "Destination": {
                    'ToAddresses': [
                        emailTo,
                    ]
                },
                "ReplyToAddresses": [
                    self.EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS,
                ],
                "Template": settings.config['TemplateName'],
                "TemplateData": replacements
            }
            print(params)
            response = ses.send_templated_email(
                **params
            )
            return True
        except ClientError as e:
            error = "There was an error sending the email"
            print(error)
            logging.error(e)
            return False
```

The email template:

```
    def confirmation(self):
        return {
            "TemplateName": os.environ['EMAIL_TEMPLATE_PREFIX']+'confirmation',
            "SubjectPart": 'Email confirmation',
            "TextPart": "Hello {{ FIRST_NAME }} {{ LAST_NAME }}, Please confirm your email address: "+os.environ['AUTH_EMAIL_URL_PREFIX']+"/{{USER_LANGUAGE}}/auth/emailconfirmation?email={{ EMAIL_ADDRESS }}&token={{ EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_TOKEN }}",
            "HtmlPart": 
            <p>Hello {{ FIRST_NAME }} {{ LAST_NAME }}, Please verify your email address <a href=\""+os.environ['AUTH_EMAIL_URL_PREFIX']+"/{{USER_LANGUAGE}}/auth/emailconfirmation?email={{ EMAIL_ADDRESS }}&token={{ EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_TOKEN }}\">here</a></p >
        }
```

Any assistance would be *very* appreciated!

Comment: The string you are passing in is evidently not UTF-8. Can you please [edit] to clarify the actual bytes you are passing in? See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: So I am fairly certain the string is UTF-8 but in my double checking I've managed to find that SES is converting it to ISO-8859-1 (you can check yourself putting in the string and it'll show what I've put above. I'll add it to the main post but I'm still at a loss as to how to correct this!

[link](https://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx)